# Can't perform credit card formatting in angular reactive form

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I am trying to perform credit card validator i.e adding space after every fourth digit like 1111 1111 1111 1111. But somehow I can't get work done.

Here is what I have tried.

Thank you in advance

html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Card number</ion-label>
    <ion-input  type ="tel" formControlName = "cardnumber" keypress ="cc_format($evet)" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

ts

```
cc_format(value) {
    var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
    var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
    var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
    var parts = []
    for (let i=0, len=match.length; i<len; i+=4) {
      parts.push(match.substring(i, i+4))
    }
    if (parts.length > 0) {
      return parts.join(' ')
    } else {
      return value
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't you want to check if the array is greater than 0: `if (parts.length > 0)`?

Comment: I tried doing it, but no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's use `ionChange` to get the changed value from your input. Connect your input with the `creditCardNumber` defined in the ts file. Now convert the credit card number and add it to the dynamic variable.

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Card number</ion-label>
    <ion-input  type ="tel" formControlName="cardnumber" (ionChange)="cc_format($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="creditCardNumber"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

```js
creditCardNumber: string;

cc_format(value: string) {
    const v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    const matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
    const match = (matches && matches[0]) || '';
    const parts = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 4));
    }
    if (parts.length > 0) {
      this.creditCardNumber = parts.join(' ');
    } else {
      this.creditCardNumber = value;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Instead of ngmodel I have set the value to the formcontolname

Comment: Happy to help ;)